# Access policies not available

Tags: azure, azure-keyvault

I am trying to enter the access policies in Azure Key Vault, but I am getting the message

"Access policies not available.
The access configuration for this key vault is set to role-based access control. To add or manage your access policies, go to the Access control (IAM) page.  in azure , how can i enter the access policies"

i already add role assignment like "
Key Vault Secrets User
" "App Compliance Automation Administrator
"   but no work.
how can i access the Access policies

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There are two ways of authorizing access to Azure Key Vault data - either using Azure RBAC roles (recommended) or using Azure Key Vault Access Policies. You cannot combine these authorization modes.

Since you have currently enabled Azure RBAC based authorization, you cannot set access policies based authorization (in fact, access policies are not even applicable in this case).

If you want to use access policies, you will need to switch the permission mode. To do so, click on "Access Configuration" in Key Vault details page in Azure Portal and make the switch.

[image]

Comment: What are the implications of using Azure Role-Based Access Control vs Vault Access Policy?